# summernote rich editor text area height become zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, summernote

I am using https://summernote.org/ rich text editor. Placed summernote editor in the bootstrap modal. on a modal show, added text using below code.

```
var text = "<p>Hello</p>";
$('text-field').summernote('code',text);
```

**problem**: sometimes it changes '.note-toolbar-wrapper' class height become zero. It looks like this.

[image]

Comment: same problem to me... do you have fix it?

Comment: Below answer works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First initialize your Summernote with element.

```
 $('your-element').summernote({
     height: 100
 });
```

And try

```
var text = "<p>Hello</p>";
$('your-element').summernote('code',text);
```

if 'text-field' is class then use `$('.text-field').summernote`.

if 'text-field' is id then use `$('#text-field').summernote`.